# Gain of power by a smart choice of goodness of fit test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, forecasting, model-evaluation, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, density-estimation

Suppose one would like to test that a sample of observations comes from Uniform(0,1) distribution. Instead of applying the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test on the sample, one may first apply the inverse CDF (quantile function) of $N(0,1)$ random variable and then apply a likelihood ratio (LR) test for $H_0\colon \mu=0,\sigma^2=1$ on these transformed observations. In finance, this idea dates back to Berkowitz ["Testing Density Forecasts, With Applications to Risk Management"](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1198/07350010152596718) (2001) who refers back to Rosenblatt ["Remarks on a Multivariate Transformation"](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2236692) (1952). Berkowitz suggests this trick allows us to gain power as LR test is uniformly most powerful (UMP).

I wonder where this power gain is coming from and at what expense (unless this is free lunch). And if this *is* free lunch, should we never use one-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test but always apply the transformation?

Answer (score 1):

There is **no free lunch**. [Berkowitz (2001)](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1198/07350010152596718) himself explains that the LR test is UMP w.r.t. a one-sided alternative such as $\mu<0,\sigma^2>1$. The **power comes from** going from a nonparametric to a parametric test. This entails **assuming the shape** of a normal curve for the transformed observations and then only examining the two moments, mean and variance. Thus it assumes away a number of violations of normality of the transformed data (uniformity of original data).

Consequently, it is **not true** that we should never use the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test on the original sample but always apply the transformation.